# Estimote Indoor navigation sdk crashes

Tags: ios

I am doing an application with Estimote Indoor navigation SDK. To set the AppId and AppToken i am using the following code. `[ESTIndoorLocationManager setupAppID:appid andAppToken:apptoken];`. But the application crashes with the error message in the console mentioned below. +[ESTBeaconManager setupAppID:andAppToken:]: unrecognized selector sent. I am using ESTIndoorLocation Manager setupAppID , but in the error its showing that unrecognized selector sent to ESTBeaconManager setupAppID. why so? 
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code looks fine, but the app is probably NOT crashing on that line, as `ESTIndoorLocationManager` is different to `ESTBeaconManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: please use `[ESTConfig setupAppID:@"yourAppID" andAppToken:@"yourAppToken"];`.

Longer [version 1.1](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-Indoor-SDK/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) we change they way in Estimote SDKs how you setup your app id and app token.

Comment: The above mentioned issue fixed, but couldn't able to build. 9 errors .

Comment: The above mentioned issue solved. Thanks . But now i couldn't able to build the project 9 errors found "._cxa_allocate_exception", "std::bad_alloc::bad_alloc()", 
 "typeinfo for std::bad_alloc", 
 "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
 "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
 "std::bad_alloc::~bad_alloc()",
"std::terminate()", 
 ___clang_call_terminate in libEstimoteIndoorSDK.a(libEstimoteIndoorSDK.a-arm64-master.o)

Comment: Please read installation guide (https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-Indoor-SDK#installation) or just use CocoaPods. You are missing -lc++ in Other Linker Flags.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed -lc++ in Other Linker Flags.